# Pattern for unit testing a form with a Captcha component inside?

Tags: forms, unit-testing, captcha, tapestry

I am currently faced with the difficult task of unit testing a form with a Captcha component inside.

By definition, a **Captcha is intended to prevent automatic submissions**. And by definition, **unit tests are automatic**.

Can someone well versed in unit testing html forms please provide advice?

(FYI, I use Tapestry 5 together with its bundled Kaptcha component - although I suspect the solution is not technology-dependent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a test mode to my application that forces the Captcha string to a well known value (I like "i8cookies").  The test mode is specified as a JVM system property at startup and simply isn't present in production mode.

Comment: Hello Howard! Is it possible to share some code? I googled for "test mode" and "java" and was not able to find any relevant info. Regards. Julien.

Comment: Or maybe direct me to relevant documentation on the web please.

Comment: I think I am almost there. I've had a look at the T5.3.1 source code for the Kaptcha and understand better what you mean now. I'll post here according to whether or not I am able to implement your solution. Best regards!

Comment: It works! I would be very grateful if you will please share with me the way to pass the JVM property to Tapestry...

Comment: JVM properties automatically become injectable Tapestry symbols, so it's pretty easy. Tapestry even handles the conversion from string to boolean (in this case), just something like:

@Inject("test-mode") private boolean testMode;

And my components and services can see this value. You need to be careful to specify a default for the symbol, however, or your app will throw an exception in production.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should put your Captcha-generator behind an interface and use a mock (or a stub) one in your unit testing.

Not sure what language you're working with, but in C# (purely so I can write example code - I think it's a pretty standard solution) you use something like this:

```
public interface ICaptchaGenerator
{
    string CreateCaptcha();
    bool IsCaptchaResponseCorrect(string originalCaptcha, string userResponse);
}
```

You then inject this into the class which needs it, using a stub or mock so you can test what happens when someone gets the Captcha correct or incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Steve. I actually use Java together with [kaptcha](http://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/). I'll try what you advised and post here accordingly.